# Create Tableau folders using REST API

Tags: api, rest, tableau-api

Has anyone successfully created folders on Tableau server using Rest API?
I am using tableauserverclient and need to create folders and subfolders.
TIA

Comment: If tableau has a REST api that allows creating folders, then I think you can assume that someone has been successful in using the API at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
new_project = TSC.ProjectItem(name=project, parent_id=parent_project_id)
self.server.projects.create(new_project)
```

Basically, one has to find the parent project id first and then create the new project using that parent project id.